# Posting with DENY privacy not working (And how to save privacy)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My android app posts a status with `deny` privacy for some friends (who cannot see), but it's not working. Here's my Graph API call:

```
POST me/feed?message=this is message &privacy='value':'CUSTOM','deny':'friend_1_id,friend2_id'}`
```

However, it's working with `allow` privacy like this:

```
POST me/feed?message=this is message &privacy='value':'CUSTOM','allow':'friend_1_id,friend2_id'}
```

1. How can I do with DENY to achieve my goal without using ALLOW?
2. (Important) How can I setting this custom privacy into user's facebook?

   Because I want Facebook app to keep this privacy (user does not need to change the setting again when using original facebook app).

Note: My app works with Facebook SDK 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I do with `DENY` to achieve my goal without using `ALLOW`

According to the facebook developers [[src](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1400750056867716)]: This is **by design**. When you use `CUSTOM` privacy, you should specify the `allow` field, or by default you'll be the **only** person that will be able to view this post.

So instead of:

```
POST me/feed?message=test&privacy={'value':'CUSTOM','deny':'[FRIEND_ID]'}
```

you should do:

```
POST me/feed?message=test&privacy={'value':'CUSTOM', 'deny':'[FRIEND_ID]', 'allow':'ALL_FRIENDS'}
```

---

#### (Important) How can I setting this custom privacy into user's facebook?

You **cannot** ever set anything that is part of the user settings, from the Graph API. This is strictly not allowed by the facebook.